# I want to compare the two sets of strings(in same array) and to print the common elements of the both in the single string in C language

Tags: c

Please provide some corrections in the syntax or provide some idea in c only. I have tried it many time but can't find the idea. I am not able to get two different string in the the same array and compare it in the function

```
#include<stdio.h>

void compare(char*  arr[])
{
    char* A[100];
    int len=0,total=0;
    for(int j=0;arr[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
        total++;
    }
    for(int i=0;!(arr[i]==44 & arr[i+1]==39);i++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    int comp=total-len;
    for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        for(int l=comp;l<total;l++)
        {
            if(arr[k]==arr[l])
            {
                A[k]=arr[l];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int m=0;m<len;m++)
    {
        printf("%c ",*A[m]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *A[100]="'1,2,3','1,2,5'";
    //scanf("%s",A);
    compare(A);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you by `44` and `39` mean the ASCII encoded characters `','` and `'\''` please use the easily understandable (and portable) characters instead. By the way, `&` is *bitwise AND*, not the logical operation which is`&&`.

Comment: Are the sets guaranteed to be sorted?  If so, it's pretty easy.

Comment: My main problem is to get two different strings in a single array and not Getting the input as a single string